# Add data of DataGridView to DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

How can i add data of DataGridView to DataSet (including column names)

well i started and stucked up in middle of the below code:

```
             DataTable table = new DataTable();
             DataRow newRow = new DataRow();
             table.Columns.Add("productname");  //first column
             table.Columns.Add("brandname");    //second column
             table.Columns.Add("quantity");     //third column
             table.Columns.Add("price");        //fourth column
```

Then I need to write this DataSet to a XML file like this

```
<stock>
    <items>   //How to add these two extra tags? ('stock' and 'items')
       ----Column Names----
    <items>
<stock>
```

Please Help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("stock");
DataTable table = new DataTable("items");
table.Columns.Add("productname");  //first column
table.Columns.Add("brandname");    //second column
table.Columns.Add("quantity");     //third column
table.Columns.Add("price");        //fourth column
```

Name your dataset and datatable as described above. It will write your xml as you need.

```
 DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
newRow["productname"] = "some value";
newRow["brandname"] = "some value";
newRow["quantity"] = "some value";
newRow["price"] = "some value";
table.Rows.Add(newRow);
ds.Tables.Add(table);
```

**Edited:**

```
string xml = ds.GetXml();
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Then how to add it to an xml file with two extra tags which i mentioned in question. i know how to write but i dont know how to add extra tags.

Comment: no actually i need to add two more parent elements to the created tables i.e "stock" and "items". as i mentioned in the question